# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "обусловлено определенными, предусмотренными законом"?

Tags: пунктуация

«вынесение процессуального акта обусловлено определенными, предусмотренными законом обстоятельствами» - нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое правило (помню по Розенталю): "Если первое определение ( у Вас это "определенными") выражено одиночным прилагательным, а вслед за ним идет причастный оборот, то такие определения считаются однородными, и между ними ставится запятая"